# Can't access child component function form parent component with View Child

Tags: angular

I'm facing an issue while using ViewChild to access a child component from a parent component. Although I can access the child component and its variables, I cannot access its public functions. I am not sure why this is happening, and I am wondering if it could be related to using standalone components, even though I have not found any documentation to support this.

Here's the child component code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'authentication-recaptcha',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RecaptchaModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './recaptcha.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recaptcha.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class RecaptchaComponent {

  @ViewChild('captchaRef', {static: true}) captchaRef!: RecaptchaPackageComponent;
  @Output() resolved = new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor(
    @Inject('RECAPTCHA_TOKEN') public token: string
  ) {
  }


  getToken(token: string) {
    this.resolved.emit(token);
  }

  execute() {
    this.captchaRef.execute();
  }


}
```

And here's the parent component code:

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RecaptchaComponent],
  selector: 'authentication-captcha',
  templateUrl: './captcha.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./captcha.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CaptchaComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() resolved = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @ViewChild('CaptchaRef',{static:true}) captchaRef!: RecaptchaComponent;

  execute() {
    this.captchaRef.execute();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.captchaRef);
  }

}
```

When I run console.log(this.captchaRef), I get the following output:

[image]

When I try to log the execute function, I get an undefined error. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: could you share a stackblitz? with the issue replicated?

Comment: Thanks for the comment but the issue was resolved when I restart my dev server it magically got fixed